# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: XXX, of entity

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

We have a ASP.NET MVC 3 C# project running NHibernate 3 and Castle.ActiveRecord for MySQL, and we trying to get  "one session per request" to work with [this tutorial](http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.Web%20applications.ashx).

And it seems to work for some stuff, but when we do `SaveAndFlush()`, the command gives us an error:

```
A different object with the same identifier value 
was already associated with the session: 142
```

And if we try to do only `Save()` we got the same message so it has nothing to do with the `Flush()` function.

I have find some result when I search but nothing I can use to get it to work.

Something I have not tested because I don't know how I do, is,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between Save(), Update(), and that Save() should only be used for _new_ persistent entities?

Comment: The text in SaveAndFlush on the object/model says that its updates if its alrady exists... we have used this for many years in our application but now when we change to "one-session-per-request" its starts to be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem might lie in that you are trying to `Save()` an object that already exists. If the object has an identifier already set (`object.Id = 142`) then the object does not need to be saved.

If you make changes to it, and need to save those changes you need to use the `Update()` method (as mentioned by @OskarBerggren) or the `SaveOrUpdate()` which basically checks and decides whether to save the object or update it. The last one might work best in your case. Change your current,

```
session.Save(object);
```

to,

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(object);
```

The `Session` object is from NHibernate's `SessionFactory` implementation. However, I see you are using `ActiveRecordMediator`, so you can use,

```
ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().CreateSession()
```

to create a `Session` you can use to save your models.